# java applet, array of buttons runtime issues

Tags: java, applet

im building a applet with a image of a java cup that can be repositioned by the clicking of 5 buttons to move it in the main area of the applet window. the code seems to compile but I get errors when trying to run it. I'm sure I'm not using the array correctly although I could be wrong. And yes guys I know AWT is old but i have to learn it for my course...any help would be great thanks guys!

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.applet.*;


 public class moveIt extends Applet implements ActionListener {

    private Image cup;
    private Panel Keypad;
    public int top = 15;
    public int left = 15;
    private Button Keyarray[];

    public void init () {
            cup=getImage(getDocumentBase(), "cup.gif");
            Canvas myCanvas= new Canvas();

            Keyarray[0] = new Button ("Up");
            Keyarray[1] = new Button ("Left");
            Keyarray[2] = new Button ("Down");
            Keyarray[3] = new Button ("Right");
            Keyarray[4] = new Button ("Center");
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);

            Panel frame = new Panel();
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(myCanvas, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frame.add(Keypad, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            Keypad.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


            Keypad.add(Keyarray[0], BorderLayout.NORTH);
            Keypad.add(Keyarray[1], BorderLayout.WEST);
            Keypad.add(Keyarray[2], BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            Keypad.add(Keyarray[3], BorderLayout.EAST);
            Keypad.add(Keyarray[4], BorderLayout.CENTER);

            Keyarray[0].addActionListener(this);
            Keyarray[1].addActionListener(this);
            Keyarray[2].addActionListener(this);
            Keyarray[3].addActionListener(this);
            Keyarray[4].addActionListener(this);


}//end of method init


public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(cup, left, top, this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String arg = e.getActionCommand();

        if (arg == "Up")
            top -= 15;
        if (arg == "Down")
            top += 15;
        if (arg == "Left")
            left -= 15;
        if (arg == "Right")
            left += 15;
        if (arg == "Center") {
            top=60;
            left=125;
        }

        repaint();

    }//end paint method

}//end of class
```

Comment: You get exception? Can you post it?

Comment: Don't compare `String`s in this way (by reference). It should be `arg.equals("Up")` and so on, also, `switch` is more preferable in this case.

Comment: this is the exeption i get: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at moveIT.int<moveIT.java:43>
at sun.applet..appletPanel.run<ApplettPanel.java:435>
at java.lang.Thread.run<Thread.java:744>

Comment: @Reign : Instead of `arg == "Up"` try using `arg.equals("Up")` and Rerun code. Check if you get same error again ???

Comment: @Suprabhat thanks yeah thats comparing the strings its a beter way to do it...still get my NPE exception i also changed my array Initialize Keyarray to :  private Button Keyarray[] = new Button[5];

Comment: @Reign : One thing i forgot to mention, i re-read your code one thing is missing try this `arg.getSource().equals("Up")`

Comment: @bigGuy it  
frame.add(Keypad, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

Comment: @Reign Keypad is not initialized? Updated my answer

Comment: @bigGuy ok so i fixed that line exception with :
private Panel Keypad = new Panel(); now it displays my applet with out exceptions but the only element that shows up it the cup.gif on the blue background, what do i do to make the rest display?

Comment: @Reign super(g); in paint method. Now you overriding applet painting. Btw, this is separate question. If original problem was fixed, accept answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize Keyarray like this:

```
private Button Keyarray[] = new Button[5];
```

Also, initialize Panel

```
private Panel Keypad = new Panel();
```

Comment: why private Button Keyarray[] = new Button[5] not?